# Why does my second update query return null? MongoDB NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

In node.js currently I am writing a function to update the values of a flashcard in two places. The flashcard document itself, and the deck where these flashcards are nested inside of as well. Updating the flashcards are working just fine but updating the deck seems a bit more tricky. Code:

```
for (let i = 0; i < currentFlashcardsArr.length; i++) {
        if (currentFlashcardsArr[i] !== newFlashcardsArr[i]) {
            console.log(i);
            const j = Math.floor(i / 2);
            const flashcardObj = deck.flashcards[j];
            const flashcardID = deck.flashcards[j]._id;
            if ((i % 2 === 0)) {
                console.log('side 1 updated');
                //query here to update items in db for flashcard side1
                await flashcard.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: flashcardID, deckId: deck._id }, { $set: { side1: newFlashcardsArr[i] } });
                let promise1 = flashcardDeck.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: deck._id, flashcards: flashcardObj }, { $set: { 'flashcards.$.side1': newFlashcardsArr[i] } });
                let result = await Promise.all([promise1]);
                console.log(result);
            }
            if (i % 2 === 1) {
                console.log('side 2 updated');
                await flashcard.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: flashcardID, deckId: deck._id }, { $set: { side2: newFlashcardsArr[i] } });
                let promise2 = flashcardDeck.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: deck._id, flashcards: flashcardObj }, { $set: { 'flashcards.$.side2': newFlashcardsArr[i] } });
                let result = await Promise.all([promise2]);
                console.log(result);
            }
        }
    }
```

whenever I submit an api call that would need to be updated on both side1 and side2 (promise1,promise2) it only updates side1(promise1) and returns null for side2(promise2) but if I were to try to only update side2, it works perfectly fine. My guess would be that there might be some error with trying to update a document that was already updated in the same query but I am not sure as of right now. This is the response I get in the console:

```
0
side 1 updated
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("6473a1f3221e4f7d03f7e8f8"),
    collectionId: new ObjectId("6472116aacd9fb3cda40215f"),
    setTitle: 'JAVA',
    flashcards: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    __v: 0
  }
]
1
side 2 updated
[ null ]
2
side 1 updated
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("6473a1f3221e4f7d03f7e8f8"),
    collectionId: new ObjectId("6472116aacd9fb3cda40215f"),
    setTitle: 'JAVA',
    flashcards: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    __v: 0
  }
]
3
side 2 updated
[ null ]
4
side 1 updated
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("6473a1f3221e4f7d03f7e8f8"),
    collectionId: new ObjectId("6472116aacd9fb3cda40215f"),
    setTitle: 'JAVA',
    flashcards: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    __v: 0
  }
]
5
side 2 updated
[ null ]
PATCH /flashcards/updateDeck 200 460.317 ms - 2
```

I am not sure what the issue it tbh.

Comment: To make it simpler to debug; does the same happen if you remove the loop and first if, hardcoding the i value? Next step would be to comment out the first operation `side 1 updated` and checking does the issue _still_happen. Simplify the code as much as you can, remove the Promise.all and just do await as well. Doing this is a nice way of focusing and debugging is trying to focus just on just the relevant bit.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a wild guess. The first part of is the conditions/query/filter that selects which document(s) to update. Your query is `{ _id: deck._id, flashcards: flashcardObj }`.

[The documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.findOneAndUpdate()) states: "Finds a matching document, updates it according to the update arg, passing any options, and returns the found document (if any) to the callback.". Sounds like your query isn't matching anything.

A few long term suggestions: think about your variable naming and logic.

In your console output `flashcards` looks like an array. In your query you have `flashcards: flashcardObj` - is `flashcardObj` an object or an array? Do you really need that as part of the filter if you have the _id? Usually the _id is enough to target a document, why do you need the flashcards? Also, model names tend to be uppecase to recognize them easier.

Comment: I'll delete my answer if it's wildly incorrect, but the suggestions should hold true

Comment: yea honestly you I have not figured out why it does not work, but I do need to refactor my code to make it cleaner, maybe seperate different parts of it and that way it will work